# Ca running OS from corrupted drive cause data corruption

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure, file-transfer, hard-drive-failure, copy

I have a slightly bad 1TB drive (2 bad sectors, that cannot be read).
I would like to use it anyway as an OS drive in my spare machine. I would not put any critical data on that drive, it would be purely for OS, programs and maybe some junk data.

But I would like to use that machine to transfer files (external drive to external drive or maybe external drive to cloud or something).

The question is... can running operating system on corrupted drive lead to data corruption in the files that the OS is working with even though the data never touch the bad drive?
ie. While copying external drive to external drive, can some of that data get corrupted?

Comment: A drive with a mere 2 bad sectors is a rare thing indeed - they usually leave the factory with more than that, but they're hidden from the user space. Drives reallocated sectors on the fly & the only time to really be worried is when the reported numbers start to increase more rapidly.

Comment: There are many operating systems and the fact that you don't restrict the applicable range to one operating system will effectively restrict the number of reasonable responses to zero responses - The one answer given does not answer your corruption question.

Comment: It is a 6 year old drive. It was perfectly fine back then. Now it is just a bit tired, but usable.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: Keep checking periodically.

e.g. run this script now and then,
it will show you any differences compared to "last time" you ran it.
and also keep files for every run  (`ls -lA ~/.smartstat*` will show you the older files)

```
$ type -a smartstat 
smartstat is a function
smartstat () 
{ 
    c="^(Device M|SMART overall-health|ID#"
    c="${c}|  2|  3|  5| 10"
    c="${c}|183|184|187|188|196|197|198"
    c="${c}|201|241|243)"
    sudo echo -n "" && echo -e "";
    lsblk | grep --color=auto disk | cut -d' ' -f1 | while read d; \
      do
        echo "=== $(sudo fdisk -l /dev/$d | head -n 1) ===";
        sudo smartctl -a /dev/$d \
        | grep --color=auto -E "$c";
        echo;
      done | tee ~/.smartstat.new;
    echo "--- diff -u0 ---";
    diff -u0 ~/.smartstat.latest ~/.smartstat.new;
    echo "--- diff -u0 --- $( \
            diff -u0 ~/.smartstat.latest ~/.smartstat.new \
          | wc -l ) lines ---";
    cp ~/.smartstat.new ~/.smartstat.$(date --iso-8601);
    mv ~/.smartstat.new ~/.smartstat.latest;
    echo -e "INTERPRETATION:\n" \
     "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.#Known_ATA_S.M.A.R.T._attributes\n" \ 
     "https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6983?page=0%2C1"
}
```

*reformatted for readability, I hope I didn't introduce errors.*

Oh...

```
$ sudo apt install smartmontools
```

... is required.